# Authorize.net login and transaction key not affected code

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, authorize.net, php-5.5, prestashop-1.5

**authorize.net** login **(xxxxx)** and transaction key **(yyyyy)** .

I changed  authorize.net module login id xxxxx to **aaaaa** and Changed transaction key yyyyy to  **bbbbb**.

Then I clicked update settings buttons. now I'm going to check in my code, New login and transaction key is not affected my code.

```
Array
(
    [x_test_request] => 
    [x_invoice_num] => 68883
    [x_amount] => 544.44
    [x_exp_date] => 0217
    [x_address] => 10842 Stanwin Ave. 
    [x_zip] => 91345
    [x_first_name] => Trent
    [x_last_name] => Davis
    [x_version] => 3.1
    [x_delim_data] => 1
    [x_delim_char] => |
    [x_relay_response] => 
    [x_type] => AUTH_CAPTURE
    [x_currency_code] => USD
    [x_method] => CC
    [x_solution_id] => A1000006
    [x_login] => xxxxxxx
    [x_tran_key] => yyyyyyyy
    [x_card_num] => 370000000000002
    [x_card_code] => 900
)
```

I want to change:

```
[x_login] => xxxxx to **aaaaa**
[x_tran_key] => yyyyy to **bbbbb**
```

Comment: do you have multishop enabled?
if not, try to search for the x_login value in the database. is usually in the configuration table.

Comment: What's your exact version of Prestashop?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corresponding code in `/authorizeaim/validation.php`:

```php
$params = array(
    'x_test_request' => (bool)Configuration::get('AUTHORIZE_AIM_TEST_MODE'),
    'x_invoice_num' => (int)$_POST['x_invoice_num'],
    'x_amount' => number_format((float)$cart->getOrderTotal(true, 3), 2, '.', ''),
    'x_exp_date' => Tools::safeOutput($_POST['x_exp_date_m'].$_POST['x_exp_date_y']),
    'x_address' => Tools::safeOutput($invoiceAddress->address1.' '.$invoiceAddress->address2),
    'x_zip' => Tools::safeOutput($invoiceAddress->postcode),
    'x_first_name' => Tools::safeOutput($customer->firstname),
    'x_last_name' => Tools::safeOutput($customer->lastname),
    'x_version' => '3.1',
    'x_delim_data' => true,
    'x_delim_char' => '|',
    'x_relay_response' => false,
    'x_type' => 'AUTH_CAPTURE',
    'x_currency_code' => $currency->iso_code,
    'x_method' => 'CC',
    'x_solution_id' => 'A1000006',
    'x_login' => Tools::safeOutput(Configuration::get('AUTHORIZE_AIM_LOGIN_ID_'.$currency->iso_code)),
    'x_tran_key' => Tools::safeOutput(Configuration::get('AUTHORIZE_AIM_KEY_'.$currency->iso_code)),
    'x_card_num' => Tools::safeOutput($_POST['x_card_num']),
    'x_card_code' => Tools::safeOutput($_POST['x_card_code']),
);
```

As mentioned by sadlyblue you should search in your database table `[your_db_prefix]configuration`:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM  `[your_db_prefix]configuration` 
WHERE  `name` LIKE  'AUTHORIZE_AIM_LOGIN_ID_%'
   OR  `name` LIKE  'AUTHORIZE_AIM_KEY_%'
```

Replace `[your_db_prefix]` with the prefix used in your database (usually `ps_`). And replace your values here.